# Grid is displayed in front of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I have a weird problem here :

[image: Screenshot]

I put the UITableview separator in pink. As you can see, there are some lines displayed in the middle and end of my cell, but with an offset. It doesn't move when I scroll, so I call it a grid that is displayed in front of my cells.
The big issue I'm facing here is that it only displays on iPhone7 simulator (IOS 10) and less (7s doesn't display this grid).

Do you guys have any idea on why and how to solve this issue ?

If you need some code, tell me and I'll edit my post.

Thanks !

Here is the xib :

```
<!--Articles-->
        <scene sceneID="j0Y-qF-3lq">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="6B8-Tk-xPz" userLabel="Articles" customClass="HeadController" customModule="E_R" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="H0o-ZU-FUz"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="DVT-NA-hNg"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Qib-nc-8lK" customClass="UITableView">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="375" height="554"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" rowHeight="90" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="oLy-kw-Uc2">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="554"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <color key="separatorColor" red="1" green="0.0" blue="0.95666110710516339" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="ArticleTableViewCell" rowHeight="90" id="owe-aQ-qV4" customClass="ArticleTableViewCell" customModule="E_R">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="90"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="owe-aQ-qV4" id="k3G-5w-mGo">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="89"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" lineBreakMode="wordWrap" numberOfLines="3" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VV9-uR-YRk">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="7" y="0.0" width="271" height="54"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name=".SFNSText" family=".SF NS Text" pointSize="13"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" lineBreakMode="wordWrap" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="T9Y-oH-4IA">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="7" y="57" width="268" height="34"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name=".SFNSText" family=".SF NS Text" pointSize="11"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Z8M-gG-zVc">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="283" y="0.0" width="88" height="88"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                                                </imageView>
                                            </subviews>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                        <accessibility key="accessibilityConfiguration" identifier="ArticleTableViewCell">
                                            <bool key="isElement" value="NO"/>
                                        </accessibility>
                                        <gestureRecognizers/>
                                        <connections>
                                            <outlet property="previewImage" destination="Z8M-gG-zVc" id="J2R-HU-hYb"/>
                                            <outlet property="subTitleLabel" destination="T9Y-oH-4IA" id="RuM-IV-kza"/>
                                            <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="VV9-uR-YRk" id="9v5-6F-3lA"/>
                                            <segue destination="BTc-SH-fsG" kind="show" identifier="ShowDetail" id="SZH-pm-QeE"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="mnh-mw-Uiz">
                        <segmentedControl key="titleView" opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="fill" contentVerticalAlignment="fill" segmentControlStyle="bar" selectedSegmentIndex="0" id="ghy-sl-9Yp">
                            <rect key="frame" x="92" y="7" width="191" height="30"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <segments>
                                <segment title="A la une"/>
                                <segment title="Tous"/>
                            </segments>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="SwitchList:" destination="6B8-Tk-xPz" eventType="valueChanged" id="a4M-GY-kSb"/>
                            </connections>
                        </segmentedControl>
                    </navigationItem>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="ArticlesList" destination="oLy-kw-Uc2" id="qXj-r7-lJg"/>
                        <outlet property="SegmentedArticles" destination="ghy-sl-9Yp" id="oTe-Vh-Kns"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="l57-G8-yDO" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="237.59999999999999" y="425.93703148425789"/>
        </scene>
```

And the image cell prototype :

[image: Image cell prototype]

Comment: Show your `prototype-cell` image.

Comment: post your xib here

Comment: See my edit. Is this ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have the answer. Very simple ! I have a TableViewController, which include a TableView. The problem was that I included another TableView in my TableViewController ! That's why I had my kind of "grid" in front of my second TableView.

Comment: how I come to know about the hierarchy of views in your storyboard. These silly mistakes cant be solve in this community. You should debug it fully and then ask for help. Anyways happy if u got a solution. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your table View rowHeight is the default one on laoding. 
Try this code in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Also hide the default separator from tableView (if you have added it as a custom line otherwise no need)

[image: Like this]

Hope it will solve this.

**UPDATE**

If you dont know how to add layout constarints and your tableView has only one type of cell then you can set the rowHeight in storyboard also. Select the tableView in your viewController and go to attribute inspector

Adding Screenshot:

Set the desired **rowHeight** here. It may fix your problem.

[image: Row height]

Comment: Nop it doesn't work ... Moreover, the layout is not good anymore.

Comment: you need to set constraints proeprly. It ll definately solve your problem

Comment: I don't have one. Do you mean constraints on table view or on cell ? (I'm new to IOS and swift)

Comment: I cannot add constraints to my cell. I can only add constraints to my tableview.

Comment: I did set my rowheight before. This did not help.

Comment: did you hide the seperators?

Comment: Yes I've set it to None

Comment: It should work man!! But don't know why setting the tableview rowHeight not fixing your issue. Try to add constraints. Look for some tutorials